# complex function in terms of z given u(x,y)

Tags: complex-analysis

For the function $ u(x,y) = e^y\cos (x)$, I have to find analytic $f(z)$ in terms of $z$.

Here's What I've done:

After Cauchy-Riemann equations and integrating, I've found

$f(z) = e^y\cos (x)-e^y\sin (x)i + ci$

To express in terms of z, I used the substitution $x = \frac{z+\overline z}{2} $ and $y = \frac{z-\overline z}{2i} $ and got:

$ f(z) = e^{\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}+\frac{z+\overline z}{2}i} + ic$ , which is in euler form.

Now, simplifying the terms in the exponent gives me $y + xi$, which is strange because that means $ f(z) = e^{\overline z i} + ic $ ??

If it is analytic, shouldn't it be expressed in terms of $z$ only (no conjugates)? I'm not sure where I went wrong and I'd appreciate it if someone could give me some advice.

Comment: Well, it should be $f(z)=e^{-iz}+ic$. Check your computation :)

Comment: @CaveJohnson Woops.After looking through for ages I've found that a very small mistake has been made in converting to euler form. Certainly didn't make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
u(x, y) = e^{y}\cos (x) = e^{y}\cos(-x)= \operatorname{Re}[e^ye^{-ix}] = \operatorname{Re}[e^{y-ix}] = \operatorname{Re}[e^{-i(x+iy)}] = \operatorname{Re}[e^{-i z}]
\end{align}

Additional: I guess $u$ can be both the real part of a holomorphic function and the real part of an anti-holomorphic function.